# How To Increment Datetime by Decimal?

Tags: formula, datetime, data-types

I have a packaged application installed in my salesforce which sends the `Service Duration` (Number Data Type) = 3,600.00 and another field `Scheduled Date Time` 12/21/2015 2:00 PM (DateTime Field Type).

I would like to calculate `Service Duration + Scheduled Date Time`, so I can get the end of the scheduled date time.

I get an error because they are of two different data types; number and Date/time.

How can I convert the number "data type" field to an hr/mins and then add that to the `Date` field .

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far? Are you trying to do this in a formula? In Apex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a `Decimal` to a `Datetime` in a formula, it represents a number of days. If you want to add **seconds**, you just need to divide by the appropriate value.

```
Scheduled_Date_Time__c + Service_Duration__c / (24 * 60 * 60)
```

If the duration were in **minutes**:

```
Scheduled_Date_Time__c + Service_Duration__c / (24 * 60)
```

**Hours**:

```
Scheduled_Date_Time__c + Service_Duration__c / 24
```

You also probably want to protect yourself against a `null` duration:

```
Scheduled_Date_Time__c + IF(ISNULL(Service_Duration__c), 0, Service_Duration__c / 24)
```

Comment: I am Trying to do this in a formula. So the addSeconds Method wouldn't be an option. Yes the "Service Duration" is listed in seconds but the "data type" is number Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addSeconds` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_addSeconds) in the `DateTime` class (I'm assuming your `Service Duration` is listed in seconds).

It works like this:

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2015, 12, 21, 14, 0, 0);
DateTime newDateTime = myDateTime.addSeconds(3600); //Service Duration
```